Cannot perform SET operation on your table in SQL from Fast API
Whenever I try to insert or post data from the API in to my departments table which is in SQL server, I get the following error [Table 'department' does not have the identity property. Cannot perform SET operation.]. However if I use Identity(1,1) on my department table on depID the data gets inserted. How do I fix this?
Following is my API code:
Models:
class Location(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Dloc'

    Locid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    locname = Column(String)

class Department(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'department'

    DEPTNO = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    DNAME = Column(String)
    Locid = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Dloc.Locid'))
    
    location = relationship('Location', backref='departments')

Schemas:
class DepartmentSchema(BaseModel):
    DEPTNO: int
    DNAME: str
    Locid: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
        `
Function:
`def create_dept(db: Session, user: schemas.DepartmentSchema):
    db_dept = models.Department(
        DEPTNO=user.DEPTNO, DNAME=user.DNAME,Locid = user.Locid
    )
    db.add(db_dept)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_dept)
    return db_dept

Main:
u/app.post("/usersandpost/", response_model=schemas.DepartmentSchema)
def create_user(user: schemas.DepartmentSchema, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
   
    return crud.create_dept(db=db, user=user)

One more thing, i am new to this API so i wanted to know that for every SQL query i want to run i have to build an entirely new function for that query. I am building a Hospital Management System which is a very vast module so for that I have lots of queries and functions to perform on database for example I have to perform crud operations on Doctors table, patients table, appointments table, labortary table and so much more. So i have to make models and schemas for each of that tables just like in the SQL server? And then build post, get, put and delete functions for each of the operations. There would be a lot of methods in that case, is that okay? Is this how apis work?
I tried to change the deptid property and used IDENTITY (1,1) on it, it worked.
But I cannot do that for all of my tables.

FYI, there is a preview feature for a reason. And the question wizard did ask you to "Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately." Please take the time to [edi] your question to correct the formatting.
